# Comparer<T>.Default Property

Tags: c#

This question comes from this [Little Wonders: `Comparer<T>.Default`](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2011/01/20/c.net-little-wonders-comparerlttgt.default.aspx)  . I am wondering what the author wrote in the line:

> If the type you want to compare already implements `IComparable<T>` or
>   if the type is `System.Nullable<T>` where T implements `IComparable`,
>   there is a class in the **System.Collections.Generic namespace called
>   `Comparer<T>` which exposes a property called Default that will create a
>   singleton that represents the default comparer for items of that
>   type.**

So for example :

I have a class :

```
class Foo : IComparable<Foo> { ... }
public class FooComparer : IComparer<Foo> { ... }
```

Comparer class implemented as `public abstract class Comparer<T> : IComparer, IComparer<T>` . My question is how Default property works overall , what it does and how it works?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Comparer<T>.Default` doesn't use your `FooComparer` class. It simply returns an instance of the internal class `GenericComparer<T>`.
This class has the constraint that `T` must implement `IComparable<T>` so it can simply delegate the calls to it `Compare` method to the `Compare` methods of the instances it gets passed.

Something like this:

```
internal class GenericComparer<T> : Comparer<T> where T : IComparable<T>
{
    public override int Compare(T x, T y)
    {
        if (x != null)
        {
            if (y != null)
                return x.CompareTo(y);
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            if (y != null)
                return -1;
            return 0;
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Looking in Reflector, for my version of the framework (4?), `Default` calls `CreateComparer()` which does... stuff with `RuntimeType`s and `CreateInstanveForAnotherGenericParameter`, whatever that is. Does that end up creating a `GenericComparer`?

Comment: @Rawling: Yes. Look more closely at that statement with the runtime type: `return (Comparer<T>)RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstanceForAnotherGenericParameter((RuntimeType)typeof(GenericComparer<int>), runtimeType);`. What that does is the following: It takes the type of `GenericComparer<int>` and creates an instance of a that generic class but with `runtimeType` as the generic argument - and not `int`.

Comment: Aha, missed that, cheers. I just saw the `extern` call and panicked.

Comment: @Rawling: Haha, I know that feeling.